# Why is locationManager:didUpdateHeading: not able to update this global?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I want to store the continuously updated values returned by the `locationManager:didUpdateHeading:` method in either a `global int` or a `property int`, so that other functions of the MotionHandler class can use it. However, this delegate method doesn't seem to be able to store its values globally but only locally. Why is that? Is it because it's not an actual MotionHandler method? How can I work around this problem? Thank you for your help.

MotionHandler.m

```
#import "MotionHandler.h"

@interface MotionHandler()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    int degrees; // the global in question..
}
@end

@implementation MotionHandler

-(void) startCompassUpdates
{
    locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    // This is working, a new value is stored in "degrees" & logged on the console after each update. However it only seems to be updating "degrees" locally..
    degrees = (int)locationManager.heading.magneticHeading;
    NSLog(@"from delegate method: %i", degrees); 
}

-(int) showDegrees
{
    return degrees; //  This is not working. Whenever I call this method, "degrees" is always zero. Why isn't this global being updated by the previous method ?
}
```

TheViewController.m

```
//...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    currentMotionHandler = [[MotionHandler alloc] init];

    [currentMotionHandler startCompassUpdates];

    while(1==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"from showDegrees method: %i",[currentMotionHandler showDegrees]); // this just keeps returning zero..
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: You aren't allowing the `viewDidLoad` method to complete due to the `while` loop.  What happens if you put the call to `showDegrees` into a timed method outside of this loop?

Comment: I didn't try it with a timer. I tried calling the showDegrees method again from inside a while loop, but this time from inside an IBAction (by clicking on a button basically) and this time it only gets the first value returned by the delegate method. Also the button I click on stays blue as if it's stuck.

Comment: Did you still have a `while` loop in your `IBAction` method?

Comment: Yes I did. Is the while loop still the problem even outside viewDidLoad?

Comment: trojanfoe is absolutely right. Your `degrees` variable IS being updated. Please ditch that `while` loop.

Comment: I'm sure you're right but why is that? Why can't I keep calling for the updating value of "degrees" to be returned to me continuously from inside a while loop?

Comment: If this while-loop of mine was being run on a background thread would I still have the same problems?

Comment: Because Cocoa is an event-based system where a runloop is used to dispatch user events to the correct window/view/whatever object.  By using a `while` loop you are hijacking this system.  Use a timer if you want (almost) constant updates.  UPDATE: Yes, running the `while` loop in a background thread **would** work, although that's a 'sledge-hammer to crack a nut'.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Maybe you can write this as an answer so that I can choose it and then others will be able to see it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As per OP request, I have transferred my comments to an answer*:

You need to stop using `while` loop to get constant feedback of the changing value.  As Cocoa Touch is an [event-based system](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html) you can't hijack its run loop by creating an infinite loop in this way.  Even outside of an event-based system, using such a tight loop would hurt performance and give little gain.

If you want continuous update (or something that appears to be continuous) you can:

1. Use a timer to call a method every *X* milliseconds (see [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html)).
2. Use a background thread (see [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

I would prefer to use the timer approach as that has the lowest overhead and runs the method in the same thread as the rest of the UI, avoiding any possible threading issue.